# Change text colour in one cell when putting text in another

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a shopping list in column B and want to be able to use the =char(10004) in column C so then the item in the cell 'B' turns green.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Please select ColumnB and Format > Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is** and:

```
=C1=CHAR(10004)
```

Choose the green formatting required and <kbd>Done</kbd>.